# Install SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am trying to install SharePoint Designer 2013, but I keep getting error.

If I run the 64-bit version I get the following message:
[image]

If I run the 32-bitversion I get the following message:
[image]

I have 32-bit and 64-bit Office products that are running fine on the same machine, why is it a problem with SharePoint? How can I install either version of SharePoint without uninstalling the products listed in the error message boxes?

I am running Windows 10 64-bit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall every 32 or 64 version, to keep only one version. You can either install everything as 32bit or everything as 64bits..
Why ? Ive no answers to that sorry